# Disable validation on a disabled textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have binding validation in a WPF application, but now because of some rules some textboxes get disabled, and the validation shows the same way. Is there a way to disable the validation when the controls are disabled and turn them back on when enabled?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the validation template when the controls are disabled.

Note, this doesn't prevent the validation rules from running, this will just remove the validation template.

If you're using a ValidationRule, you can obtain a reference to the textbox, and check to see if the textbox is enabled.

**Place the following in your textbox style:**

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
         Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: ok i see, but i would need a total stop of the validation becouse the button next has rules on it too.

Comment: and how can i get the textbox reference inside the validation rule class? that way it could be easyer to  implemente that.

Comment: I having a problem in the trigger property is doe not recognize isEnabled!